# android - create database to store texts

Tags: android, database

I want to create an app which allows to store texts into a database, so other users can call it, too.
Is there a way to create such a database without any costs? E.g. with a free webspace or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use free web hosting services like

[000webhost](https://www.000webhost.com/) or [ByetHost](https://byet.host/)

Just make an JSON API php file which you will send data to, and then you can store that data in MySQL database. That's one way to do it

Comment: Are there tutorials to set it up for android usage?

Comment: Json is commonly used by many android applications for receiving and sending data to webservers.
You need knowledge of php for making api. As far as I understood you are trying to send data to file and then store it in mysql database? And then use it?

Comment: Yes, one user stores a text in the database and another user has access to it

Comment: What kind of information are you trying to store?
DO you have enough knowledge to send POST/GET requests to specific file on web from android application?

Comment: It should only be able to store texts. Yes, theoretically I know it, I'm just missing the know-how on building servers and experience with phpmyadmin and stuff like that - that's why I'm asking if it's even possible to do it just with webspace.

Comment: Of course it is, but you will need to hire php developer, because stackoverflow is not a place for free coding.

Comment: That's not the intention, I can set it up myself - the question was just if it is possible to handle it and the traffic with amwebspace and not an own server

Comment: Of course you can, there is no difference whether you have your own server or someone else own it. You just need an working web server which will respond to your requests.

Comment: So when I use webspace - do I need a computer that is providing it which runs all the time?

Comment: Of course, but that is not your computer it's web hosting companies server like byethost or 000webhosting i mentioned above. You place content on web hosting and that server serves the content 24/7.

Comment: But I still need PhpMyAdmin e.g. to set it up with set/get - method, don't I? But how does it work then, when it's not running continually?

Comment: Dude what are you talking about.
You get FREE or PAID hosting, they care of such things. You have phpmyadmin, and everything set up and ready to use.
And of course it is running continually 24/7/365. Learn what is web hosting on internt